# Heroku table cache rate suddenly dropping

Tags: postgresql, heroku, caching

My standard-0 postgres database performed an automatic update yesterday and since then my table cache rate has dropped from 100% to hovering around 78% causing massive latency spikes as many requests are being read from disk now. I didn't deploy any code changes around this time so I don't know what went wrong.

Recent Heroku Postgres log:

```
sample#current_transaction=429551949 sample#db_size=11524477599bytes sample#tables=59 sample#active-connections=22 sample#waiting-connections=0 sample#index-cache-hit-rate=0.98709 sample#table-cache-hit-rate=0.8726 sample#load-avg-1m=1.785 sample#load-avg-5m=1.165 sample#load-avg-15m=0.715 sample#read-iops=951.94 sample#write-iops=27.614 sample#tmp-disk-used=543600640 sample#tmp-disk-available=72435191808 sample#memory-total=8036332kB sample#memory-free=66712kB sample#memory-cached=7508352kB sample#memory-postgres=89876kB sample#wal-percentage-used=0.06650554816207192
```

I've tried using `pg:diagnose` to identify indexes that could be optimized yet it only raised it to 80%. I've even tried recently upgrading to a standard-2 tier thinking I've out grown the previous plan although it has already dropped to 91% only 10 minutes of usage.

I feel like I've tried everything from `VACUUM ANALYZE FULL` to caching expensive queries results. I don't understand what could've happened that would cause this and would love if anyone has had a similar experience to share, thanks.

Comment: *"My standard-0 postgres database performed an automatic update ... "* Are we supposed to know what that means?

Comment: Heroku has postgres databases that will require maintenance every so often and after a certain window it'll automatically be applied.

Comment: Your "recent db log" doesn't look like a PostgreSQL log entry.  Is that from some middleware?

Comment: That's also a Heroku specific log, sorry should've clarified that.